# How is this site using SASS (scss) files directly, instead of compiled CSS?

Tags: sass

If you go to http://www.lpkbrands.cn/work/beam-suntory/ and inspect the styling, you'll notice that the CSS files are not CSS files, but instead uncompiled SASS files. How is this possible? I'm trying to reverse engineer it for a client, but I've never seen such a thing.

Edit: As someone said they don't see SASS, look at this screenshot from Chrome:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.  There are no .sass or .scss files referenced anywhere in that document.  The only stylesheets being served here are .css.

Comment: Probably source maps? @cimmanon

Comment: It's reading the sourcemap, yes, but there's no Sass being served here.

Answer (score 1):

There are no sass at all. Only CSS

If you go to the page, open the inspector and check the Networks tabs and reload the page, order by type.
You would see 3 files in css

[language-selector.css?v=3.3](http://www.lpkbrands.cn/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/css/language-selector.css?v=3.3)

[settings.css?ver=5.1.6](http://www.lpkbrands.cn/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/css/settings.css?ver=5.1.6)

[main.css](http://www.lpkbrands.cn/wp-content/themes/lpk/dist/styles/main.css)

What you're seeing is the sourcemap, that point to the sass file where that css code is located  ( they should remove sourcemaps for production (just my opinion)  but well, there he is )

If you want to know more about sourcemaps please read [this awesome article by TheSassWay.com](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/using-source-maps-with-sass) well explained.